# Sprite retaining a copy of original position after it is moved

Tags: actionscript-3

I have never seen this happen before. I have some very simple code to display a Sprite and move it around. I first add it to the stage with this code:

```
public var floor:Floor;
    public var char:Character;

    public function Game() 
    {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void{
        floor = new Floor();
        addChild(floor);

        char = new Character();
        addChild(char);
        char.x = stage.stageWidth - char.width;


        var item:Sprite = new Sprite();
        item.graphics.beginFill(0x666600);
        item.graphics.drawRect(400, 400, 50, 50);
        item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveEast);
        addChild(item);
    }
```

That last bit with the graphics is just for testing; basically, I want a button that I can press and have it shift everything by 50 pixels. This is the moveEast function:

```
public function moveEast(e:Event):void {
        floor.x += 50;
    }
```

As you can see, it is very straightforward. In theory, I should add my Floor object, then move it to the right 50 pixels whenever I push the button. However, in practice, what happens is that is both shifts and doesn't shift. Specifically, it does shift; I can move it all the way across the stage and have the complete object move. However, it ALSO retains a copy of the object at the original position. I am confident that I have not accidentally added another child somewhere. If I remove the single addChild(floor) line from my code, then nothing shows up. Any ideas on why it might be doing this?

Comment: It sounds like `init` is running twice, have you tried popping a `trace` in to check?

Comment: Oh my! You're right! I had forgotten to remove the event listener, so it was firing in both the capture and bubble phases. Thank you so much! I don't think I would have ever caught that; I spent several hours on it last night and had no idea.